# Is there a command in Powershell to flash window?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that takes a long time to run and I often don't know when it's finished unless I check.

Is there a command that I can stick to the end of my powershell script that can notify me when the scripts are run, kind of like the Communicator chat window turns yellow on the menu bar when someone messages me notifying me to go check?

Comment: You could use [Growl](http://www.growlforwindows.com/), which is a pop-up notification thing. I understand that it is drivable by PowerShell.

Answer (score 3):

You can import FlashWindowEx from user32.dll as shown in this article http://learn-powershell.net/2013/08/26/make-a-window-flash-in-taskbar-using-powershell-and-pinvoke/

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Window
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct FLASHWINFO
    {
        public UInt32 cbSize;
        public IntPtr hwnd;
        public UInt32 dwFlags;
        public UInt32 uCount;
        public UInt32 dwTimeout;
    }

    //Stop flashing. The system restores the window to its original state. 
    const UInt32 FLASHW_STOP = 0;
    //Flash the window caption. 
    const UInt32 FLASHW_CAPTION = 1;
    //Flash the taskbar button. 
    const UInt32 FLASHW_TRAY = 2;
    //Flash both the window caption and taskbar button.
    //This is equivalent to setting the FLASHW_CAPTION | FLASHW_TRAY flags. 
    const UInt32 FLASHW_ALL = 3;
    //Flash continuously, until the FLASHW_STOP flag is set. 
    const UInt32 FLASHW_TIMER = 4;
    //Flash continuously until the window comes to the foreground. 
    const UInt32 FLASHW_TIMERNOFG = 12; 

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool FlashWindowEx(ref FLASHWINFO pwfi);

    public static bool FlashWindow(IntPtr handle, UInt32 timeout, UInt32 count)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = handle;
        FLASHWINFO fInfo = new FLASHWINFO();

        fInfo.cbSize = Convert.ToUInt32(Marshal.SizeOf(fInfo));
        fInfo.hwnd = hWnd;
        fInfo.dwFlags = FLASHW_ALL | FLASHW_TIMERNOFG;
        fInfo.uCount = count;
        fInfo.dwTimeout = timeout;

        return FlashWindowEx(ref fInfo);
    }
}
"@
```